# Getting iOS Font preview programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering. Is there any possible way to get an iOS font preview of a selected font programmatically in swift.

Thanks...

Comment: Use an NSAttributedString with the selected font.

Comment: Is the _user_ getting the preview (text font changes to whatever user chooses) or are _you_ getting the preview (in Xcode)?

Comment: @TroyT Yes I want the user able to change the font ...